# How to debug a Windows DLL used inside Python?

Tags: python, windows, dll, clr

On Windows7 I have a python script that uses Windows DLLs, using the .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR). An error occurs inside one of the used DLL, but the standard Python debugger only debugs on the Python code level (and not the DLL).

How can I debug what is going on inside the DLL(s)?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or do you have Visual Studio available?

Comment: No - do you recommend to install it? Can I then run my code within Visual Studio to debug the code?

Comment: Install Visual Studio.  Once you do that, then you can debug the DLL easily (assuming you have the source code, if not, then you have to debug assembly language).

Comment: My answer below outlined the general way to debug DLL's that will be called by the external program.

Answer (score 11):

If you have Microsoft Visual Studio available,

1) open the Visual Studio project that your DLL is part of (or create a new project).

2) If you have set up your DLL for debugging (you've built it with debugging info, and it will be the one that your python program will use), you can set breakpoints in the DLL code.

3) Start the program you want to debug as you would do normally.

4) Go back to the Visual Studio IDE and go to the `Debug` menu.  Choose the `Attach to Process` option.  You will then get a list of all the running processes.

5) Choose the process you want to debug, which will be your python program, or runtime that is running your program.

6) Sit back and wait for one of your breakpoints to be hit, or you can try a `Break All` from the Debug menu to temporarily halt the program.

This is a general way of starting out debugging not only python programs, but any program where you need to debug a DLL that is being used by the program.

Note that the above advice works best if you have built the DLL yourself with debugging information and is being utilized by your python application.  If it is a third-party DLL where you have no source code, you can still debug from Visual Studio, but will need to know assembly language (since the source code is usually not available).

Comment: Also remember (in 2017 at least) to select Native from the drop down if your debugging say a standard C++ DLL as it defaults to "python".   It stops at breakpoints and everything.  Neat!  I had no idea you could do this.

Comment: I have tried this but the debugger does not load the symbols of my dll. I have no idea how to force it loading the symbols and stopping in my c# dll.

Answer (score 0):

These 3 debugging scenarios with pythonnet are based on PTVS docs:

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Various-debugging-scenarios-of-embedded-CPython