# ctypes wintypes WCHAR String Additional White Spaces

Tags: c++, python-3.x, dll, ctypes, wchar-t

Why is every character followed by a white space in the following?

**C++ DLL**

test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_DLL_H
#define TEST_DLL_H
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall 

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

namespace Test_DLL
{
    struct Simple
    {
        TCHAR a[1024];
    };

    extern "C"
    {
        int EXPORT simple(Simple* a);
    }
};

#endif
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

int EXPORT Test_DLL::simple(Simple* a)
{
    std::wcout << a->a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Python**

test.py:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes


class MyStructure(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", wintypes.WCHAR * 1024)]


a = "Hello, world!"
hDLL = ctypes.LibraryLoader(ctypes.WinDLL)
hDLL_Test = hDLL.LoadLibrary(r"...\test.dll")
simple = hDLL_Test.simple
mystruct = MyStructure(a=a)
ret = simple(ctypes.byref(mystruct))
```

The result:

```
H e l l o ,   w o r l d !
```

Is the problem on the C++ DLL side? Or am I missing something on the Python side?

Comment: `TCHAR a[1024]` -- A `TCHAR` is not guaranteed to be a wide character type.  Did you build your DLL using Unicode as the character set?  Or better yet, just state up front `wchar_t` and skip the `TCHAR` stuff.

Comment: Yes, the DLL is built using Unicode character set. I replaced `TCHAR` with `wchar_t`, but no difference. I'm using `TCHAR` because the actual DLL I'll have to use in the end has that type in its documentation. My task is to use a DLL developed by someone else, so I can't change the C++ source code. I decided to start small with my own simple example to see how things work (I'm new to `ctypes`). But I don't like seeing these additional white spaces in this small example, as the same may happen when I use the actual DLL.

Comment: Inspect the string you're printing by seeing exactly what the byte sequence is.  The spaces aren't put there due to the printing function.  The string itself has some sort of byte sequence, where the first byte is ASCII and the second is NULL or some other character (all the earmarks of some sort of miscommunication between ASCII and Unicode/wide chars in your setup).

Comment: Weird... I changed the printing part to `std::wcout << p->m_szExeDir[0] << p->m_szExeDir[1] << std::endl;` and the result is `H e `. So the first two characters seem to be `H` and `e`, but the displayed result has additional white spaces. Is this what you suggested by inspecting the string?

Comment: I can't duplicate the error, maybe I have newer python version. It looks like there is a problem with redirecting the output back to python. Put `MessageBoxW(0, a->a, 0, 0)` in C++ program to see if it receives the buffer correctly.

Comment: Obviously you are outputting wide characters.  Look at the internals of the buffer you're using.  Don't use output statements -- all bets are the whitespace is the extra byte that follows the letters.  For example `0x48` followed by `0x00` followed by `0x65` followed by `0x00`, etc.  Again, the issue is not going to be discovered by trying to output the characters.  You need a lower-level view, i.e. a debugger to look at the characters located at the memory address.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I'm using Python 3.6.6. Using the function you suggested seems to produce the desired result. That is, the pop-up window shows the string without additional spaces.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Mmmm... how would I use a debugger in this case? The execution starts in Python: I first initialize a structure, then pass it to a function defined in a C++ DLL to print the information. I just want to make sure what's passed to the DLL is correct.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154325/how-to-debug-a-windows-dll-used-inside-python/27154618#27154618)

Comment: Thanks! I did that and verified that the string has the characters in the expected positions. In this case, `a->a` is of the type `wchar_t[1024]` and its value is `L"Hello, world!"`. So I don't know why `std::wcout` is printing those white spaces.

Comment: I tried this in Windows 10, python 3.6.6, and it works. I am using Visual Studio. The DLL is also made with Visual Studio. I think your *.dll is made with MinGW (32-bit version?) and the problem is probably on C++ side. Use `WriteConsole` instead of `std::wcout` to output text in console window.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2015. The function `WriteConsole` doesn't seem to write on the same output as `std:cout`, because I don't see anything after the Python script finishes running.

Comment: On which *Python* version are you able to reproduce the problem? (please mention the ones that you can't as well)

Comment: @Bruno -- *L"Hello, world!"* -- No, go to the memory window and look at the actual bytes, starting from the address of where the string resides.  What you're showing us is the debugger doing a "pretty print", almost no different than `wcout`.  Those blank spaces *are* there in the string -- you're not using the right tool in the debugger to see them.  Like I stated, it is an ASCII 'H', followed by a null, then an ASCII 'e', followed by a null.  Those nulls are the "blank space" you're seeing.  Or `48 | 00 | 65 | 00` etc... -- that is an idea of what you should be seeing.

Comment: Also remember that a wide character is 2 bytes.  So you know what the first byte is -- it is the second byte of that character that is responsible for the blank space.

Comment: Test with `DWORD n; WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), L"abc", 3, &n, 0);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Here's what I see on VS: https://imgur.com/nR9xASe. Is this the memory window you're talking about?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani That also doesn't display anything.

Comment: @Bruno No.  `Debug -> Windows -> Memory`.  Enter the address of the first character.  You will then see the bytes.

Comment: You're right... https://imgur.com/89KveqB. It shows `48 00 65 00 ...`. Then what's causing this? And how do I fix it? Of course I don't want to pass nulls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning I thought that it's some minor problem in your code. When debugging I discovered that it isn't quite so. Starting from your example, I developed another one that illustrates some key points.

*test.h*:

```cpp
#if !defined(TEST_DLL_H)
#define TEST_DLL_H


#if defined(_WIN32)
#  if defined(TEST_EXPORTS)
#    define TEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define TEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
#  define CALLING_CONVENTION __cdecl
#else
#  define __TEXT(X) L##X
#  define TEXT(X) __TEXT(X)
#  define TEST_API
#  define CALLING_CONVENTION
#endif


namespace TestDll {
    typedef struct Simple_ {
        wchar_t a[1024];
    } Simple;

    extern "C" {
        TEST_API int CALLING_CONVENTION simple(Simple *pSimple);
        TEST_API int CALLING_CONVENTION printStr(char *pStr);
        TEST_API int CALLING_CONVENTION wprintWstr(wchar_t *pWstr);
        TEST_API wchar_t* CALLING_CONVENTION wstr();
        TEST_API void CALLING_CONVENTION clearWstr(wchar_t *pWstr);
    }
};

#endif  // TEST_DLL_H
```

*test.cpp*:

```cpp
#define TEST_EXPORTS
#include "test.h"
#if defined(_WIN32)
#  include <Windows.h>
#else
#  include <wchar.h>
#  define __FUNCTION__ "function"
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <iostream>

#define PRINT_MSG_0() printf("From C: - [%s] (%d) - [%s]\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
#define WPRINT_MSG_0() wprintf(L"From C: - [%s] (%d) - [%s]\n", TEXT(__FILE__), __LINE__, TEXT(__FUNCTION__))

#define DUMMY_TEXT_W L"Dummy text."


//using namespace std;


int TestDll::simple(Simple *pSimple) {
    //std::wcout << pSimple->a << std::endl;
    WPRINT_MSG_0();
    int ret = wprintf(L"%s", pSimple->a);
    wprintf(L"\n");
    return ret;
}


int TestDll::printStr(char *pStr) {
    PRINT_MSG_0();
    int ret = printf("%s", pStr);
    printf("\n");
    return ret;
}


int TestDll::wprintWstr(wchar_t *pWstr) {
    WPRINT_MSG_0();
    int ret = wprintf(L"%s", pWstr);
    wprintf(L"\n");
    int len = wcslen(pWstr);
    char *buf = (char*)pWstr;
    wprintf(L"Hex (%d): ", len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len * sizeof(wchar_t); i++)
        wprintf(L"%02X ", buf[i]);
    wprintf(L"\n");
    return ret;
}


wchar_t *TestDll::wstr() {
    wchar_t *ret = (wchar_t*)malloc((wcslen(DUMMY_TEXT_W) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
    wcscpy(ret, DUMMY_TEXT_W);
    return ret;
}


void TestDll::clearWstr(wchar_t *pWstr) {
    free(pWstr);
}
```

*main.cpp*:

```cpp
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#if defined(_WIN32)
#  include <Windows.h>
#endif


int main() {
    char *text = "Hello, world!";
    TestDll::Simple s = { TEXT("Hello, world!") };
    int ret = simple(&s);  // ??? Compiles even if namespace not specified here !!!
    printf("\"simple\" returned %d\n", ret);
    ret = TestDll::printStr("Hello, world!");
    printf("\"printStr\" returned %d\n", ret);
    ret = TestDll::wprintWstr(s.a);
    printf("\"wprintWstr\" returned %d\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes


DLL_NMAME = "./test.dll"
DUMMY_TEXT = "Hello, world!"


WCharArr1024 = ctypes.c_wchar * 1024

class SimpleStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("a", WCharArr1024),
    ]


def main():

    test_dll = ctypes.CDLL(DLL_NMAME)

    simple_func = test_dll.simple
    simple_func.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(SimpleStruct)]
    simple_func.restype = ctypes.c_int
    stuct_obj = SimpleStruct(a=DUMMY_TEXT)

    print_str_func = test_dll.printStr
    print_str_func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
    print_str_func.restype = ctypes.c_int

    wprint_wstr_func = test_dll.wprintWstr
    wprint_wstr_func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_wchar_p]
    wprint_wstr_func.restype = ctypes.c_int

    wstr_func = test_dll.wstr
    wstr_func.argtypes = []
    wstr_func.restype = ctypes.c_wchar_p

    clear_wstr_func = test_dll.clearWstr
    clear_wstr_func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_wchar_p]
    clear_wstr_func.restype = None

    #print("From PY: [{:s}]".format(stuct_obj.a))
    ret = simple_func(ctypes.byref(stuct_obj))
    print("\"{:s}\" returned {:d}".format(simple_func.__name__, ret))
    ret = print_str_func(DUMMY_TEXT.encode())
    print("\"{:s}\" returned {:d}".format(print_str_func.__name__, ret))
    #ret = wprint_wstr_func(ctypes.cast(DUMMY_TEXT.encode(), ctypes.c_wchar_p))
    ret = wprint_wstr_func(DUMMY_TEXT)
    print("\"{:s}\" returned {:d}".format(wprint_wstr_func.__name__, ret))
    s = wstr_func()
    print("\"{:s}\" returned \"{:s}\"".format(wstr_func.__name__, s))
    #clear_wstr_func(s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Changes**:

- Removed the *C++* layer (to exclude as many variables as possible) and only rely on *C*
- Adapted the code to be *Nix* compliant (I've run it on *Ubtu*, but I encountered other issues that I'm not going to discuss)
- Added more functions (this was a debugging process), to gather as much intel as possible
- Did some renames, refactorings and other non important changes
- While investigating, I discovered a funny problem (the coment from *main.cpp*). Apparently ***simple* function compiles even if I don't prepend the namespace in which it's declared. This doesn't apply for the other functions.** After some quick tries, I realized that it's because of the *Simple* argument (probably because it's also part of the namespace?). Anyway, didn't spend too much time and didn't get to the bottom of it (yet), probably it's ***Undefined Behavior*** (and it only works because of dumb luck)
- The narrow and wide functions are mixed, that's a *NO - NO*, and is only for debugging / demonstrating purposes

**Output**:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054269984>"c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x64
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054269984>dir /b
> code.py
> main.cpp
> test.cpp
> test.h
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054269984>cl /nologo /DDLL /DUNICODE /MD /EHsc test.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:test.dll
> test.cpp
>    Creating library test.lib and object test.exp
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054269984>cl /nologo /DUNICODE /MD /EHsc main.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /OUT:main.exe test.lib
> main.cpp
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054269984>dir /b
> code.py
> main.cpp
> main.exe
> main.obj
> test.cpp
> test.dll
> test.exp
> test.h
> test.lib
> test.obj
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054269984>main.exe
> From C: - [test.cpp] (23) - [TestDll::simple]
> Hello, world!
> "simple" returned 13
> From C: - [test.cpp] (31) - [TestDll::printStr]
> Hello, world!
> "printStr" returned 13
> From C: - [test.cpp] (39) - [TestDll::wprintWstr]
> Hello, world!
> Hex (13): 48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F 00 2C 00 20 00 77 00 6F 00 72 00 6C 00 64 00 21 00
> "wprintWstr" returned 13
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054269984>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> F r o m   C :   -   [ t e s t . c p p ]   ( 2 3 )   -   [ T e s t D l l : : s i m p l e ]
>  H e l l o ,   w o r l d !
>  "simple" returned 13
> From C: - [test.cpp] (31) - [TestDll::printStr]
> Hello, world!
> "printStr" returned 13
> F r o m   C :   -   [ t e s t . c p p ]   ( 3 9 )   -   [ T e s t D l l : : w p r i n t W s t r ]
>  H e l l o ,   w o r l d !
>  H e x   ( 1 3 ) :   4 8   0 0   6 5   0 0   6 C   0 0   6 C   0 0   6 F   0 0   2 C   0 0   2 0   0 0   7 7   0 0   6 F   0 0   7 2   0 0   6 C   0 0   6 4   0 0   2 1   0 0
>  "wprintWstr" returned 13
> "wstr" returned "Dummy text."
> ```

- It seems to be *Python* related
- The strings themselves are not messed up (their lengths and *wprintf* return value are correct). It's more like *stdout* is the culprit

Then, I went further:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054269984>for /f %f in ('dir /b "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064*"') do ("e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\%f\Scripts\python.exe" code.py)
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054269984>("e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_02.07.15_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py )
> Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> From C: - [test.cpp] (23) - [TestDll::simple]
> Hello, world!
> "simple" returned 13
> From C: - [test.cpp] (31) - [TestDll::printStr]
> Hello, world!
> "printStr" returned 13
> From C: - [test.cpp] (39) - [TestDll::wprintWstr]
> Hello, world!
> Hex (13): 48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F 00 2C 00 20 00 77 00 6F 00 72 00 6C 00 64 00 21 00
> "wprintWstr" returned 13
> "wstr" returned "Dummy text."
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054269984>("e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.04.04_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py )
> Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> From C: - [test.cpp] (23) - [TestDll::simple]
> Hello, world!
> "simple" returned 13
> From C: - [test.cpp] (31) - [TestDll::printStr]
> Hello, world!
> "printStr" returned 13
> From C: - [test.cpp] (39) - [TestDll::wprintWstr]
> Hello, world!
> Hex (13): 48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F 00 2C 00 20 00 77 00 6F 00 72 00 6C 00 64 00 21 00
> "wprintWstr" returned 13
> "wstr" returned "Dummy text."
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054269984>("e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.05.04_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py )
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> F r o m   C :   -   [ t e s t . c p p ]   ( 2 3 )   -   [ T e s t D l l : : s i m p l e ]
>  H e l l o ,   w o r l d !
>  "simple" returned 13
> From C: - [test.cpp] (31) - [TestDll::printStr]
> Hello, world!
> "printStr" returned 13
> F r o m   C :   -   [ t e s t . c p p ]   ( 3 9 )   -   [ T e s t D l l : : w p r i n t W s t r ]
>  H e l l o ,   w o r l d !
>  H e x   ( 1 3 ) :   4 8   0 0   6 5   0 0   6 C   0 0   6 C   0 0   6 F   0 0   2 C   0 0   2 0   0 0   7 7   0 0   6 F   0 0   7 2   0 0   6 C   0 0   6 4   0 0   2 1   0 0
>  "wprintWstr" returned 13
> "wstr" returned "Dummy text."
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054269984>("e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py )
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> F r o m   C :   -   [ t e s t . c p p ]   ( 2 3 )   -   [ T e s t D l l : : s i m p l e ]
>  H e l l o ,   w o r l d !
>  "simple" returned 13
> From C: - [test.cpp] (31) - [TestDll::printStr]
> Hello, world!
> "printStr" returned 13
> F r o m   C :   -   [ t e s t . c p p ]   ( 3 9 )   -   [ T e s t D l l : : w p r i n t W s t r ]
>  H e l l o ,   w o r l d !
>  H e x   ( 1 3 ) :   4 8   0 0   6 5   0 0   6 C   0 0   6 C   0 0   6 F   0 0   2 C   0 0   2 0   0 0   7 7   0 0   6 F   0 0   7 2   0 0   6 C   0 0   6 4   0 0   2 1   0 0
>  "wprintWstr" returned 13
> "wstr" returned "Dummy text."
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054269984>("e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.02_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py )
> Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> F r o m   C :   -   [ t e s t . c p p ]   ( 2 3 )   -   [ T e s t D l l : : s i m p l e ]
>  H e l l o ,   w o r l d !
>  "simple" returned 13
> From C: - [test.cpp] (31) - [TestDll::printStr]
> Hello, world!
> "printStr" returned 13
> F r o m   C :   -   [ t e s t . c p p ]   ( 3 9 )   -   [ T e s t D l l : : w p r i n t W s t r ]
>  H e l l o ,   w o r l d !
>  H e x   ( 1 3 ) :   4 8   0 0   6 5   0 0   6 C   0 0   6 C   0 0   6 F   0 0   2 C   0 0   2 0   0 0   7 7   0 0   6 F   0 0   7 2   0 0   6 C   0 0   6 4   0 0   2 1   0 0
>  "wprintWstr" returned 13
> "wstr" returned "Dummy text."
> ```

As seen, the behavior is reproducible starting with *Python **3.5***.

I thought it is because of [[Python]: PEP 529 -- Change Windows filesystem encoding to UTF-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0529), but that's only availalbe from version *3.6*.

Then I started reading, (I even tried to do a diff between *Python 3.4* and *Python 3.5*)  but with not much success. Some articles that I went through:

- [[MSDN]: Windows with C++ - Using Printf with Modern C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn913181.aspx)
- [[MSDN]: VS2005, console, Unicode, wcout fails](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94eec320-3874-4067-b31e-31d2e3703acf/vs2005-console-unicode-wcout-fails?forum=vcgeneral)
- [[Python 3]: What’s New In Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html)

Then I noticed [[SO]: Output unicode strings in Windows console app (@DuckMaestro's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app/9051543#9051543) and started to play with [[MS.Docs]: _setmode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2015).

Adding:

```c
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


static int set_stdout_mode(int mode) {
    fflush(stdout);
    int ret = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), mode);
    return ret;
}
```

and calling it like `int stdout_mode = set_stdout_mode(_O_TEXT);` in *test.cpp* before outputting anything from *C* (**and** *C++*: `std::wcout` line uncommented), yielded:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054269984>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Hello, world!
> From C: - [test.cpp] (32) - [TestDll::simple]
> Hello, world!
> "simple" returned 13
> From C: - [test.cpp] (40) - [TestDll::printStr]
> Hello, world!
> "printStr" returned 13
> From C: - [test.cpp] (48) - [TestDll::wprintWstr]
> Hello, world!
> Hex (13): 48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F 00 2C 00 20 00 77 00 6F 00 72 00 6C 00 64 00 21 00
> "wprintWstr" returned 13
> "wstr" returned "Dummy text."
> ```

- Although it works, I do not know why. It could be ***Undefined Behavior***

  - Printing *_setmode*'s return value, revealed that *Python 3.4* and also *main.exe* automatically set the mode to ***_O_TEXT*** (***0x4000***), while newer *Python* versions (those that don't work) set it to ***_O_BINARY*** (***0x8000***) - which apparently **seems to be the cause** (might be related: [[Python]: Issue #16587 - Py_Initialize breaks wprintf on Windows](https://bugs.python.org/issue16587))
  - Trying to set it to any of the wide related constants (*_O_U16TEXT*, *_O_U8TEXT*, *_O_WTEXT*) crashes the program when calling *printf* or `std::cout` (**even if restoring the original mode when done with wide functions** - before the narrow ones)
- Trying to output real *Unicode* chars, won't work (most likely)
- You could achieve the same goal on *Python* side: `msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), 0x4000)`

Comment: Oh wow... that's crazy! Thanks a lot for all this investigative work! And I thought it was something simple! So I guess the answer seems to be, and correct me if I'm wrong, that there's not a definitive explanation of/fix to the issue. Actually, my situation got a bit better since I got a C++ code that interacts with the final function I needed to call. So I don't need to pass `wchar_t` from Python anymore, because I created another layer (in C++ and a DLL) that sits between Python and the target function in yet another DLL. :)

Comment: There might be a simpler alternative, I just don't have it :). There is certainly an explanation. As I wrote in the 3rd last bullet, *Pyton **3.5+***  , sets *stdout*'s mode to *\_O\_BINARY*, while older ones and *main.exe* set it to *\_O\_TEXT*. Apparently for *\_O\_TEXT* it works, or that's why it works. By setting I don't mean explicitly calling the function, it's just the value that's set by default.

Comment: I am confused because the asker says `WriteConsoleW(...L"abc"...)` doesn't work in C++. This is totally unrelated to Python, except that the console window belongs to Python. Maybe Python is doing some console initializing which C++ doesn't like. That might explain why `_setmode` fixes it. By the way, which Windows version do you have?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: *WriteConsoleW* didn't come up til now. Is *wcout* calling it behind the scenes (my knowledge is fairly limited in this area)? ?That's my point too, newer *Python* versions set binary mode for the console (didn't put my finger on it, yet) and as an effect *C++* (and also *C*) output garbage. But I don't know why, nor does it make sense to me. I am running on *Win 10*.

Comment: Actually it seems Visual Studio's implementation for `std::wcout` uses `WriteFile`, not `WriteConsoleW`. I think your original assumption about `_setmode` makes sense.