# Random AccessViolationException in multithread simulation when using LoadLibrary to P/Invoke methods

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have an application in C# that simulates multiple mathematical models written in C++ in parallel(each model in a thread). Each model has 4 methods : Init, Run, Free and Save. Each method is dynamically loaded using LoadLibrary from kernel32. Using the LoadLibray method, we load the DLL and then using GetProcAddress we get the 4 main methods. The application has Play/Pause/Stop.

When we Play the simulation for the first time, there's no problem in the simulation but, if we Stop and Play again, after a couple of seconds, the program throws AccessViolationException in the Run method of a RANDOM model. There's no pattern, which makes me belive that problem lies in the P/Invoke operation. Look at the following example :

```
//The C++ Dll.

extern "C" __stdcall void Init(const char* name, int size, void* buffer, void** memory);

extern "C" __stdcall void Run(int in_size, int out_size, void* in_buffer, void* out_buffer, void** memory);

extern "C" __stdcall void Free(void** memory);

extern "C" __stdcall void Save(int size, void* buffer, void** memory);


// after the P/Invoke Dll and Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer method (in C# code)

ModelInit(string name, int size, IntPtr buffer, ref IntPtr memory);

ModelRun(int in_size, int out_size, IntPtr in_buffer, IntPtr out_buffer, ref IntPtr memory); // <---- THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE

ModelFree(ref IntPtr memory);

ModelSave(int size, IntPtr buffer, ref IntPtr memory);
```

I have no idea how to debug this, i've already tried to make  c++/cli wrapper to avoid P/Invoke, but some DLLs has third-party libraries that were built in /MTd option, and the C++/CLI is incompatible.

Comment: A C# `string` and a `const char *` are not the same.  A C# `string` could be Unicode.  As to how to debug this, [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154325/how-to-debug-a-windows-dll-used-inside-python/27154618#27154618)

Comment: For debugging, just check “enable native code debugging” in C# project settings then click Debug / Start debugging, F5 on my keyboard layout. It will break on the C++ line which causes the exception.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The linked answer is for Python. Native debugging is _much_ simpler for C#, no need to attach to processes.