# How to call c++ .dll from C# in client?

Tags: c#, c++

[on windows 10-vsto 2019]

After created some functions in the header file stad.h like this :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void  __cdecl Callthis(int i, char* buf)
{
    ... // 
     
}
//end file
```

I copied this .dll to the c # project's release directory(same folder) and called it via the function:

```
    [DllImport(assemblyname)]
    public void Callthis(int k, byte[] buf)
    {
    }
    public string pf_Call(int len, int index)
      {
        byte[] o = new byte[len + 1];
        Callthis(index, o);
        ....
      }
```

The function has been called on my pc. However, after installing .exe setup on the client (windows8,7: \AppData\Roaming\myfolder) Other components are working
except assembly can't call this function (maybe it can't find this the .dll location) so I tried changing some settings in the hope it was called:

[c++ setting/addition include directory] $(APPDATA)\myfolder;
However it still does not work..

can you show me to get it called on the client?
Thanks you!

Comment: Is VC++ redistributable package installed on client pc?

Comment: What error message do you get when you make the call ?  Is an exception thrown ?  If so what is the exception ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with full error details

Comment: You should also be able to debug into the DLL to see if the actual function does get called.

Comment: Hi, I have installed the c++ package 2015-2019, 32-64bit redistribution respectively, However, it still doesn't work and didn't get any errors. I would probably have to debug it, but unfortunately my knowledge is only limited to pinvoke. Many thanks for the comments

Comment: @Mindex If you built the DLL, the open the DLL project in Visual Studio and start your C# application there. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154325/how-to-debug-a-windows-dll-used-inside-python/27154618#27154618).  It talks about Python, but debugging C# would be similar or same steps.

Comment: Hi @PaulMcKenzie, thanks for the suggestions, this will be of great help to me.

Comment: What compiler options are you using?  AnyCPU and X86?  You may built and tested with an Intel processor and client may have an AMD.  Or you may of tested on a 64 bit machine and client has a 32 bit machine.

Comment: Hi @jdweng,My computer(win10-64bit), I have built c#anycpu. I then tried running on win8,7-64bit. I have not tested 32bit yet.

Comment: Does client have same version of Net that you used to build?  You probably need to publish application and then install using setup.exe on client machine.  The setup updates windows dlls to match the versions on the build machine.  The Net Library for many of the methods are just wrappers that call windows dlls.  If the versions of Windows dlls are different code may not work.  So your c# executable is calling Net dlls which call Windows dlls.

Comment: Make sure all the drivers on the client machine are the latest for windows7/8.  You are probably using new drivers on your win10 machine.  They are probably backwards compatible to win7/8, but some features may not be available on older drivers (or bugs were fixed).