# Fortran C++ binding - wrong value being read in DLL(C++)

Tags: c++, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying to use Fortran with C++. I created a DLL(C++) by following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-160). However, instead of creating C++ `MathClient.cpp` program, which calls this DLL (as it is described in the guide), I created Fortran `MathClient.F90` program, which calls this DLL.

Fortran main code:

```
PROGRAM MAIN

  USE MOD_INTERFACE

  IMPLICIT NONE
  
  INTEGER(C_INT) :: A, B
  INTEGER(C_INT) :: INDEX
  INTEGER(C_INT) :: CURRENT
  LOGICAL(C_BOOL) :: BOLEAN
  
  A = 1
  B = 1

  ! Initialize a Fibonacci relation sequence.
  CALL FIBONACCI_INIT(A, B)
  ! Write out the sequence values until overflow.
  DO
      
    BOLEAN = FIBONACCI_NEXT()
    IF (.NOT. BOLEAN) EXIT
    INDEX = FIBONACCI_INDEX()
    CURRENT = FIBONACCI_CURRENT()
    WRITE(*,*) INDEX, ': ', CURRENT
  
  END DO
  
  WRITE(*,*) FIBONACCI_INDEX() + 1, &
  'Fibonacci sequence values fit in an unsigned 64-bit integer.'

  END PROGRAM MAIN
```

Fortran module code:

```
MODULE MOD_INTERFACE

USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING

INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE FIBONACCI_INIT ( A, B ) bind ( C, name = "fibonacci_init" )
      IMPORT
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER (C_INT) :: A, B
    END SUBROUTINE FIBONACCI_INIT
    
    LOGICAL(C_BOOL) FUNCTION FIBONACCI_NEXT ( ) bind ( C, name = "fibonacci_next" )
      IMPORT
      IMPLICIT NONE
    END FUNCTION FIBONACCI_NEXT
  
    INTEGER(C_INT) FUNCTION FIBONACCI_CURRENT ( ) bind ( C, name = "fibonacci_current" )
      IMPORT
      IMPLICIT NONE
    END FUNCTION FIBONACCI_CURRENT

    INTEGER(C_INT) FUNCTION FIBONACCI_INDEX ( ) bind ( C, name = "fibonacci_index" )
      IMPORT
      IMPLICIT NONE
    END FUNCTION FIBONACCI_INDEX

END INTERFACE

END MODULE MOD_INTERFACE
```

The C++ functions in `MathLibrary.cpp` are the same as in the above-mentioned guide. The only difference is, that I add some `std::cout`, in order to print values of received variables in C++ functions.

The problem is, that C++ functions receive **wrong** integer(`C_INT`) values from Fortran main code. For example, the void `fibonacci_init` function should receive values `current_ = 1, previous_ = 1` during initialization. Instead of that, the values are some huge integer numbers (`current_ = 45028402782009632`).

I am using Intel Parallel Studio and Visual Studio. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Double check int size and calling convention.  Step through the call at the assembly level to see what Fortran returns and what the marshaling code gives to C++.

Comment: What is the prototype of your C functions? Should the interfaces give the Value attribute to the dummy arguments?

Comment: See [Call specific C++ DLL from Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64281930/call-specific-c-dll-from-fortran). It sounds like the C functions expect the arguments by value, but Fortran passes them by reference.

Comment: @dxiv and @IanBush you are both right. I forgot to pass those variables by ```VALUE```. Also the ```C_INT``` should have been replaced by ```C_LONG_LONG```, After these modifications, it is working. Thanks!