# char array in C++ function doesn't correspond to Character array from Fortran calling program

Tags: c++, string, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

system:

```
Mac OSX Catalina
GCC 10, GFORTRAN 10
```

I have this simple fortran program that calls a C++ void function.  The purpose is a toy example of passing a string from Fortran to C++ based on what I have been finding in examples, but something is not right

```
# subf.f90
program main
  use iso_c_binding
  character(len=256), target :: a_string

  interface
     subroutine print_string(fortran_string) Bind(C)
       use iso_c_binding
       TYPE(C_PTR) :: fortran_string
     end subroutine print_string
  end interface

  a_string = "Hello world" // C_NULL_CHAR
  print *, "trying to print: ", trim(a_string)
  print *, "a string of length: ", len(trim(a_string)) - 1
  call print_string(C_LOC(a_string))
end program main
```

```
// sub.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

extern "C" {
  void print_string(const char * fortran_string);
}

void print_string(const char* fortran_string) {
  std::string forstring(fortran_string);
  std::cout << "sizeof fortran_string: " << sizeof fortran_string << std::endl
            << "strlen of fortran_string: " << strlen(fortran_string) << std::endl
            << "first char: " << fortran_string[0] << std:: endl
            << ".length(): " << forstring.length() << std::endl
            << "the actual string: `" << forstring << "`" << std::endl;
}
```

I compile and run with `g++-10 sub.cpp -c && gfortran subf.f90 sub.o -o sub -lstdc++ && ./sub`

The first character always seems to be `p` and the size of the passed string is always the same but where is `p` coming from?, why is the string garbage? and why doesn't the size match what I sent over from fortran?

Here is a sample output:

```
> ./sub
 trying to print: Hello world
 a string of length:           11
sizeof fortran_string: 8
strlen of fortran_string: 6
first char: p
.length(): 6
the actual string: `p$??`
```

Comment: I think you have the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65553923/fortran-c-binding-wrong-value-being-read-in-dllc#comment115899570_65553923 - your interface needs the value attribute for passing the C_ptr

Comment: And if you give `fortran_string` the `value` attribute? And do you have a reason to use `type(c_ptr) [,value] :: fortran_string` instead of `character(kind=c_char) :: fortran_string(*)`?

Comment: @francescalus both of those suggestions work, and from the question referenced from Ian Bush, it also works to leave the Fortran Code unmodified and change the C function signature to accept the pointer by reference.  All in all, I appreciate the character(kind=c_char) approach as I can remove pointers.  Thanks much