# Interfacing a C++ dll with Excel 2016

Tags: c++, excel, vba, visual-c++, dll

I am trying to run a function in Excel from a dll made via C++.

I have followed the steps in the [Microsoft DLL creation overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-160) and successfully gotten the DLL/client example working. I've also found the [Access DLLs in Excel article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/how-to-access-dlls-in-excel) helpful.

Ultimately what I want to do is just square a number, once I have that working I can inch forward. The hangup is with the parameters my function is receiving.

As you can see below I'm using some txt file output to help debug the process, and I feel like I'm close.

Here is my MathLibrary.h:

```
// MathLibrary.h - Contains declarations of math functions
#pragma once

#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" MATHLIBRARY_API double get_var(double *my_var);
```

Here is my MathLibrary.cpp with the target function "get_var"

```
// MathLibrary.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL.
#include "pch.h" // use stdafx.h in Visual Studio 2017 and earlier
#include <utility>
#include <limits.h>
#include "MathLibrary.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<sstream>


double WINAPI get_var(double *my_var)
{
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("C:\\Users\\my_username\\Desktop\\example.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile << my_var;
    myfile << "\n";
    //myfile << *my_var;
    myfile.close();
    return 25.0;
}
```

Everything above builds ok.

Here is my VBA:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function get_var _
Lib "C:\Users\my_username\source\repos\MathLibrary\x64\Debug\MathLibrary.dll" (ByRef my_var As Double) As Double
```

Now here's the interesting part. I have no problem sending data *from* the DLL. The number 25 returns as expected:
[image]
[image]

But here are the contents of the example.txt

```
Writing this to a file.
0000000000000001
```

Meaning the pointer clearly isn't getting the address to the 5.5 parameter I'm passing. So it's really just getting the parameters in that's causing me the headache.

I've tried most every combination of changing the C++ side from accepting pointers, to dereferenced pointers, to outright double types, and passing using ByRef and ByVal on the VBA side, but to no avail.

My Excel/VS setup is
[image]
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: *As you can see below I'm using some txt file output to help debug the process* -- You really should learn to use the debugger to debug DLL's.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154325/how-to-debug-a-windows-dll-used-inside-python/27154618#27154618).  Even though it pertains to Python, the same steps are used to debug any language calling into the DLL.

Comment: Also, I doubt anything is wrong with the C++ code.  Pointers don't work differently just because the function is being called from Excel.  The C++ code doesn't care who is calling.  Thus the issue is more than likely on the Excel side, where the marshalling of the data over to the DLL function is incorrect.

Comment: Try `myfile << (uintptr_t)my_var;` instead.

Comment: @dxiv hmm that seems to break the code, as now it returns "#VALUE!" and does not write the file

Comment: @mgd That wasn't expected. I just meant it to doublecheck that the `1` was indeed a 64-bit `1` value, and not the result of some accidental conversion. Anyway, that change alone could not have possibly caused the behaviors to change, so there must be something else going on there.

Comment: @dxiv my apologies you're totally correct, I had a small typo in my original attempt, looks like the output is now:

Writing this to a file.
1

Comment: Well, if you're getting `1`, that indicates you are not passing an address.  An address value of `1` says to me that Excel is not marshalling a pointer to the C++ code.  BTW, how do you know that the `5.5` you see there is being sent as a `double`?  If it were Visual Basic proper, then it is easy to see just by looking at the code -- a picture of an Excel cell doesn't really indicate what is actually being done on the Excel side.  That could just be a character string or some other type for all we really know.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah you nailed it, if I write a separate VBA subroutine and dim x as double, the above example works great, printing the address to the file, and if I dereference the pointer I can square it and return. Is there a way to accept your comment as the answer?

Comment: Well, I know that VB works, just never done anything interfacing with Excel.  So I leave it to a real Excel / VBA expert to explain things a lot better than I could.

Comment: @mgd That makes *some* sense. I guess it solves the immediate problem, though it doesn't explain what was happening before, and I don't know Excel well enough to even speculate. FWIW the `1` could be a [`VT_NULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypes/ne-wtypes-varenum) [variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/how-to-access-dlls-in-excel#argument-types-in-cc-and-vba), though I don't see why such a variant would be passed by value to a function declared to expect a `double` reference.

Comment: Yes quite bizarre, and to make things even more frustrating I made a get_type function in VBA that simply returns the type of whatever is passed to it (using the VBA typename function). When I execute get_type(5.5), ie the same as my question example input, it returns Double. I think you are correct that the 1 represents VT_NULL however, as that would explain why any attempt to dereference that pointer in get_var's implementation caused Excel to crash when the get_var function call was made. Maybe Excel makes all inputs to its functions variant types and later changes it behind the scenes?

Comment: @mgd From [Argument types in C/C++ and VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/how-to-access-dlls-in-excel#argument-types-in-cc-and-vba): "*Excel only passes Variants of the following types to a VBA user-defined function ... Double - VT_R8*". I don't know, however, how that works when the function is explicitly declared with an incompatible prototype. That is the part where a better Excel/VBA connoisseur would need to fill-in the dots.

Comment: How the Excel sheet calls the UDF and how VBA calls it are two different things. You have exposed the function to Excel directly but you are asking it to supply a reference: I don’t think that will work: let’s say that you changed the value of the double pointed to by my_var ... what would the spreadsheet do with that? So, try passing the parameter as a double (not a pointer) in your dll code, and declaring the VBA parameter as ByVal. That said, I have never tried exposing a dll function directly as a UDF, but always used a VBA wrapper. Also are you compiling as x64?

Comment: Yeah that was my next instinct after the above failed (use double instead of double * and ByVal instead of ByRef), but that implementation did not appear to work either, though it did not crash the program. It just returned zero in Excel (or in actuality a very small number when I printed that number to the txt file).

Comment: As this is not a “recognised” way of calling a dll function as a spreadsheet function, it may be a case of trial and error to find out what type Excel is actually passing to the function (eg Excel has a variant-style type XLOPER that it passes to .xlls in addition to the basic types). Better to write a VBA function with the ByVal signature and pass the parameters to the dll call perhaps?