# How to debug a dll using Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, dll

How can I debug a dll using visual studio?

I have the DLL source, pdb, etc.

I tried these options:

[image]

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    void DebugBreak();

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
      //...
    }
    break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    {
     //...
    }
    break;
    }
);
    return TRUE;
}
```

It launches the exe but doesn't inject the DLL, by default this exe didn't load the DLL, im manually injecting it.

Is possible to visual studio attach the DLL? and be able to put breakpoints on it, view call stack on a crash, etc?

Comment: Do you have the Symbols file (`*.pdb`) for that `.dll` file? If not, then VS isn't the right tool - you should use a tool like Ghidra or IDA.

Comment: @Dai Yes i do, i also have the source, but i dont understand how to properly use visual studio to debug my dll

Comment: What do you mean when you say you're "manually injecting the dll"? Are you calling `LoadLibrary`/`LoadLibraryEx` to manually pull in a dll at runtime? Or something else?

Comment: @ComicSansMS yes

Comment: Put a call to [`DebugBreak`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-debugbreak) at the start of `DllMain`.

Comment: @Raja [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154325/how-to-debug-a-windows-dll-used-inside-python/27154618#27154618).  Your screenshot does not indicate what project you loaded, the application's project or the DLL's project.

Comment: @RichardCritten this way?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie im loading the dll project

Comment: @Raja Then there is something wrong with your setup.  You shouldn't have to resort to doing anything other than setting a breakpoint.  Are you sure the DLL that is running is the one you're actually debugging?  Do you have multiple copies of that DLL on your system, and Windows is finding the one that you are not debugging?  What does the Output Window say when it loads the DLL?  Does it say "symbols not found" or similar?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the problem is the dll doesnt get injected into the process, even using the option debug> attach to process and selecting the exe

Comment: @Raja You didn't answer my questions.  What does the Output Window say concerning whether the symbols could be found?

Comment: Also when i hover any breakpoints it pops a tooltip `"the breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest way to fix this is via the Modules Window in the Debugger:

1. Put a breakpoint after your `LoadLibrary` call.
2. Go to *Debug->Windows->Modules* in the menu bar to bring up the Modules window.
3. Search for your dll file in the list. In the *Symbol Status* column
   it should read "Cannot find or open the PDB file".
4. Right click the dll and choose *Load Symbols* from the context menu.
5. Point it to the correct pdb file.
6. The *Symbol Status* should now change to "Symbols Loaded".

You should now be able to step into functions from the dll and put breakpoints.

Comment: Inst possible from the DLL source make it attach to the process while debugging from the visual studio? i mean, when selecting the process to attach it also attach the DLL, without me manually injecting it from another source.

Comment: @Raja Not from within the source, no. The best you can do is help Visual Studio find the PDB file on its own by [configuring the debugger to look in the correct place automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022) (or make sure the PDB file ends up in a place where it looks by default). But you will have to do that again for each new installation of Visual Studio that you want to debug on.